loop a fluid simulation over continuing frames
I would like to create a small but accurate fluid simulation that I could then repeat in a loop for additional frames.   Consider a dripping faucet where for a given period the identical drips continue, until perhaps it gets turned off of flows at some higher rate.



I've considered perhaps creating an external script that could copy external cache files and change key-frame portion of filenames for such a loop.  Would that work... if I then increase the simulation end-frame so these files are used in rendering?  Or is there some internal indicator of what external cache files are valid and these would be ignored?
Is this when I should purchase Flip Fluids add-on or some other that includes such looping features?
Other suggestions welcome in order to save large amounts of simulation time.
Attached is an example file that has a short (22ish) frame simulation of a drip that I'd like to repeat over and over for hundreds of frames without the simulation overhead of simulating more that these few frames.

While this example simulates in a short time, I have a more detailed simulation with Diffusion and High Visc Solver settings that takes quite a while over some 80 frames; therefore my motivation to find a low-cost, imperfect repeat-mode solution.
I am aware of some solutions for cloth using an MDD export and Mesh Cache modifier, but of course cloth generally deals with a single closed (manifold?) mesh.
